# Which rsync client can I use on windows 7?

Tags: windows, software-rec, rsync

I would like to know if, beside [cwRsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/cwrsync), there exists a good rsync client for Windows (and more specially Windows 7 x64).

This client should support the following operations :

- backup of a directory (from a Linux server to that Windows box)
- mirroring of a directory (synchronizing a "music" directory on both Windows box and Linux one, or the aforementioned backup directory).

Ideally, this client should have a "reasonably nice" UI, without all those command line quirks I've learn to dislike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well rsync is a command line tool like most of the *nix tools. Therefore the native rsync application is a command line tool.

I only know of one rsync based tool with a GUI for Windows: [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp)

But is is only a regular win32 application, not a native 64 bit application.
But as rsync doesn't need much memory a 64bit version would not get you any advantages.